# Kubernetes get endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, nsq

I have a set of pods providing nsqlookupd service.
Now I need each nsqd container to have a list of nsqlookupd servers to connect to (while service will point to different every time) simultaneously. Something similar I get with

```
kubectl describe service nsqlookupd
...
Endpoints: ....
```

but I want to have it in a variable within my deployment definition or somehow from within nsqd container

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you would need an extra service running either in your `nsqd` container or in a separate container in the same pod. The role of that service would be to pole the API regularly in order to fetch the list of endpoints.

Assuming that you enabled [Service Accounts](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/service-accounts/) (enabled by default), here is a proof of concept on the shell using `curl` and `jq` from inside a pod:

```bash
# Read token and CA cert from Service Account
CACERT="/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt"
TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)

# Replace the namespace ("kube-system") and service name ("kube-dns")
ENDPOINTS=$(curl -s --cacert "$CACERT" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-dns \
)

# Filter the JSON output
echo "$ENDPOINTS" | jq -r .subsets[].addresses[].ip
# output:
#   10.100.42.3
#   10.100.67.3
```

Take a look at the source code of [Kube2sky](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/dns/kube2sky/kube2sky.go) for a good implementation of that kind of service in Go.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with a StatefuSet. Stable names + stable storage